# How to debug a service, who does not start up due to a "TypeInitializationException"

Tags: c++, xml, windows-services

I'm working on a Windows service. Previously it was starting up and I could do some debugging, but now this is not the case anymore, due to a `TypeInitializationException`. The situation is the following:

I'm using Windows task manager's `Service` tab to start up the service.
After not even one second, I get following error message (dialog box):

```
The operation could not be completed.
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Why is this an issue?

1. The service starts with a `Sleep(10000)`, so nothing should happen for at least 10 seconds (the time I need to perform an "Attach to process").
2. In the registry, I've filled in value 180000 into the  or value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout`, so I should not have the mentioned dialog box before 3 entire minutes.

The reason that I know that I'm facing a `TypeInitializationException` is that I find this as explanation in the event log, the complete content of the  tag is the following:

```xml
<Data>Application: [Windows-Service].exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException at <Module>._initterm(Void ()*, Void ()*) at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializeNative(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport*) at <Module>..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException</Data>
```

Does anybody know what that exception is about and/or how I can know which line of code is causing it?

By the way, I tried using the language support using `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` but I don't see the typical XML parsing. What I am doing wrong?

Added after UKMonkey's comment:

As suggested by UKMonkey, in the meanwhile I've found out which line is responsible for the mentioned issue, here it is:

```cpp
output_stream = std::ofstream(output_file);
```

where `output_file` is a public property of the corresponding class, and is defined there as:

```cpp
char* output_file;
```

Does this mean anything to anybody?

Comment: 'previously it was starting up and I could do some debugging' So revert; retest (because maybe it's not your program causing the problem) and then diff to work out what you changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last edit indicated what was wrong: the mentioned property definition needs to be corrected as follows:

```
char* output_file = "";
```

In other words, in case of a `TypeInitializationException` all properties (in header or source files, I don't know) need to be verified and initialised, if needed.

@UKMonkey: thanks for the advise.